# About $\chi^2_\text{adjusted}$

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

I am reading "*An Introduction to Error Analysis: The Study of Uncertainties in Physical Measurements by J. R.Taylor*", and I read the following formula in an exercise:

$$\chi^2_\text{adjusted}=\sum_{k=1}^2\frac{\left (|O_k-E_k|- \frac{1}{2}\right )^2}{E_k}$$

but I don't know when using it! In particular:

- Is $\chi^2_\text{adjusted}$ used when $d=\text{degrees of freedom}=1$ and $k=2$?
- Is $\chi^2_\text{adjusted}$ used when $d=\text{degrees of freedom}=1$?

The exercise is:

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: So the text says it's an adjustment applicable when you have one degree of freedom, and gives a reference which presumably motivates the choice and perhaps extends it to other cases. (Perhaps, wild-guessing, the adjustment term is $\frac 1{d+1}$, which would vanish with many degrees of freedom.) To the library with you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\chi^2$ statistic is independent of the number of degrees of freedom. But converting that statistic to some type of $p$-value *does* depend on the degrees of freedom. That is, you calculate $\chi^2$, then with that number and the degrees of freedom you look it up the $p$-value in a $\chi^2$ table.

As for the "corrected" version of this test, you may find the WP page for [Yates continuity correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates%27s_correction_for_continuity) helpful. The extra 0.5 term in the numerator is there to compensate from modeling a discreet distribution using a continuous distribution. Some claim it overcompensates in certain circumstances. True, but I've found it gives *closer to exact* results in nearly all case.

Comment: of course, I know it.. I use $\mathcal{P}_d(\tilde\chi^2 \geq \tilde\chi_O^2)$ (with $\tilde{\chi}_O^2=\displaystyle \frac{\chi^2}{d}$ and $\chi^2=\sum_{k=1}^n \displaystyle\frac{(O_k-E_k)^2}{E_k}$); therefore Why Do Taylor uses $\chi^2_\text{corrected}$ in exercise?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates's_correction_for_continuity